# Domain objects with runtime-only properties

Tags: c#, n-tier-architecture

I have a typical n-tier application with Data/Domain/UI layers. The domain objects initialise themselves from the DataLayer, but also contain additional state properties that get updated on a 2-second timer. These properties are not written to the DataLayer.

This design requires that the domain objects persist for the life of the application. This is causing problems with data binding to the UI as the domain objects out-live the various UI displays.

I understand the norm is to "new up" a domain object, display it to the UI and then dispose of it. However, my state properties are stopping me from doing this as these would be lost on dispose. I don't really want to store my 2-second state data to the database. What are my options?

Am I attacking this problem from a fundamentally flawed perspective?

**Edit 1:**

For instance, My Domain object includes a "Live Reading" property which it picks up from an external process every 2 seconds. My UI Layer binds to this property to display this, continually updating, value.

Comment: What's the state properties on your domain object ? Why they are for the purpose of the UI ? It seems that the reposibilities of your layers are leaking and mixing together.

Comment: Domain objects should document your domain language by themselves. If there are some strange ethereal properties appearing in them then something is definitely wrong. Either they belong to a new domain object (as you suggested) or to the infrastructural layer and should not "pollute" the domain layer, or your domain objects should be modified to express their new behavior/state explicitly.

Comment: OK, I think I've got it now. Only database data is mapped to generic Domain objects. My live data needs to be separate from this in a different layer. Thanks for the comments.